# Measuring a 10-30 ns pulse width

Tags: arduino, high-frequency

For my school project over summer holidays I was tasked to measure a 10-30 ns impulse of a laser. So far I got the impulse on the oscilloscope, which I will run through a Schmitt-Trigger to get a square wave for easier measuring.

The result I want to output to an Arduino for easier comparison with my min/max values. But the Arduino can't measure at such low times, therefore I looked into possible solutions and came across the [TDC 2700](https://www.ti.com/product/TDC7200). Due to my lack of understanding of high-frequency measuring and electronics in general I find it hard to understand the datasheet.

It says the TDC has a resolution of 55 ps, but wouldn't I need an incredibly high frequency on the CLK pin for that? AFAIK there aren't any quartz oscillators with frequencies over ~200 MHz.

Comment: Another way would be to convert your impulse to a much slower waveform with a charge amplifier circuit, which you could read directly with the microcontroller. This works only if the pulses are not too frequent.

Comment: Syco, Which Schmitt trigger, specifically? (It takes some care go be sure that the rising delay and falling delay are enough similar for what may be your purpose.)

Comment: Measure the laser electrically (driving side) or optically (output side)?

Comment: Note that there are devices out there (frequency synthesizers) that take an input clock of 5 MHz and can output a programmable frequency up to around 30 GHz.  So this addresses your concern about the frequency range of quartz oscillators.

Comment: What resolution/accuracy do you need in your measurement?

Answer (score 2):

Much simpler, you could use an analog "timer" ...
Adjust R2 & C1 to your needs.

[image]

Comment: I'm missing some explanation on how the circuit works (gated current source, etc.)

Comment: It is just a gated "current source" driven by the pulse (if alone). You must just sample the voltage at the end of the pulse.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of measuring the time directly, let the ns pulse gate a current into a capacitor and then measure the voltage in the capacitor with one of the slow A/D converters in the Arduino.

Reconfigure the input pin from A/D input to output for a short moment after measuring and tie it to ground to discharge the cap. Or use another output for that.

This works ok if your ns pulses are not too frequent so you can be sure that you only ever catch one pulse. If they are more frequent you need an external synchronizer flipflop that disables the gate automatically as soon one pulse had been detected and another output that can reset that flipflop.

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet covers the questions you are asking. The external clock is specified as 8MHz for most of the specifications, which is a convenient frequency for oscillators. Note the jitter requirements in the datasheet.

Internally the chip uses a TDC (time to digital converter) in addition to a simple counter. The ring oscillator operates at a very high frequency (not publicly disclosed), plus there is some analog magic used to get the specified resolution, the 8MHz clock is to calibrate the ring oscillator (which will drift with temperature and is not accurate to begin with).

[image]

However minimum start-to-stop time is specified as 12ns so on the surface unsuitable for your application, which requires a 10ns measurement. But perhaps you can relax that requirement or add a fixed relatively stable delay of a few ns that can later be subtracted digitally.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a school project I guess it is about learning, so here are two important EE skills:

- Make the most out of the tools you have (did you know a soundcard can measure phase shift between two sine waves with picosecond resolution?)
- If that is not practical, build your own tools.

In this case you have a scope that can display the pulse. I assume it's a modern digital scope so it will also be able to trigger on it, record it, then measure and display the pulse width on screen.

Then the scope is probably going to have an ethernet or USB port which you can use to talk to it. So you can use python and pyvisa to get all the measurements, without building any hardware.

This method is quick to implement but it is not very fast: each measurement means the PC and the scope have to talk together, and this stuff is usually pretty slow, so don't count on thousands of acquisitions per second. If it's done in real time, maybe 10 measurements/s, it depends on how fast the scope is on the VISA side. The scope will also be able to record as many waveforms as its memory will allow with minimal dead time between waveforms, then the python script can replay them and measure them.

Now if the pulses are frequent enough that the scope can't keep up, then you have to make your own stuff, in this case a time to digital converter, which is what the other answers are suggesting.